# Why after downloading Excel (xlsx) file from server, File is corrupted and not able to open?

Tags: jquery, excel, spring

I am trying to download an xlsx file from the server using spring. File gets download but its showing an alert that file is corrupted!

Here is my code:

```
 File file = new File(outputPath+ fileName);
 FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
 response.setContentType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-
 officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
 response.setContentLength((int) file.length());        
 response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename="+fileName);
 FileCopyUtils.copy(fis, response.getOutputStream());
```

JSP Page:

```
$("#download").click(function(){
  if($(this).data('clicked', true)){
    window.location="http://localhost:8080/IRI-AXCO/downloadFile";
  }
}
```

Here is the snapshot:

[image]

Help is appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Show your full controller method.

Comment: Hi I got the solution, I changed the contenttype to CSV format', thanks for your reply

Answer (score 0):

Myself found the solution,

```
@GetMapping("/downloadFile")
    public void download(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)throws Exception{
        try {
            fileName=fileName.replace(" ", "_");
            File file = new File(outputPath+ fileName);
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
            Path source = Paths.get(outputPath+ fileName); 
            String contentType=Files.probeContentType(source);
            response.setContentType(contentType);
            response.setContentLength((int) file.length());
            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename="+fileName);
            FileCopyUtils.copy(fis, response.getOutputStream());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

The above code gave me the result!